# Calculating from a column of dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that I am splitting into a list based off of its date.
Once split I am planning to calculate two things: (i) difference between most recent date and the split dates, and (ii) the mean of a column within the dataframe within the newly created list splitDate.

This dataframe had 2 dates so it created a list of 2 dataframes.

```
rawDM <- data.frame(DM =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    Date=c.Date(2015-11-22, 2015-11-22, 2015-11-22, 2015-11-22, 2015-11-22, 2015-11-20, 2015-11-20, 2015-11-20, 2015-11-20, 2015-11-20))

rawDM$Created.Date <- as.Date(rawDM$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
maxDate<-max(rawDM$Created.Date) #calculates most recent date

rawDM$amendDate<- maxDate-rawDM$Created.Date # amount of days from max date
splitDate <- split(rawDM, list(rawDM$amendDate)) #splits based off of amended dates
rawDM <- subset(rawDM, select = c(DM, Created.Date, amendDate))

splitMean <- as.list(mean, splitDate$*$DM) # this is where I am having issues
```

The expected outcome would have splitMean = list of the mean of the column DM of all dataframes within the list splitDate. However I don't want to hard code selecting each dataframe, because the amount of variable dates is unknown. Is there a function to run the mean, on all dataframes containing the column DM?

Comment: Thank you Akrun, I have edited the whole post; please let me know1

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Please check if that helps

Answer (score 0):

We need to loop through the 'splitDate', extract the 'DM' column and get the `mean`.  For this, we can use one of the apply family functions like `sapply/vapply`

```
vapply(splitDate, function(x) mean(x$DM, na.rm=TRUE), 0)
# 0 2 
# 8 3
```